# how to calculate the rate of return for a list of prices in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to get a rate of return for a list of prices in excel using python. I wrote the following code but I can't find out what the problem is.

```
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    close = sheet.cell(row, 5)
    returned = sheet.cell(row, 7)
    operation = pd.DataFrame.pct_change(close)
    returned.value = operation
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEu8U.png)

this is the error that I keep getting:
axis = self._get_axis_number(kwargs.pop("axis", self._stat_axis_name))
AttributeError: 'Cell' object has no attribute '_get_axis_number'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post a sample of your excel so we might help you better

Comment: I just posted part of the data set. Would that help?

Comment: PLEASE PROVIDE THE SAMPLE AS A TXT TO TEST IT!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using pct_change for `Close`, you didn't need to going through loop. Just simple like that:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('StackOverFlow.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

df['Operation'] = df['Close'].pct_change()

df
```

[image]

Besides that, I suggest you utilize pandas dataframe by field name, it could be easier for maintenance

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    close = row['Close']
```